# Renaming a dataframe dynamically based on output of pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Im trying to Condense my data in a format so it would be more useful , Data Format:

```
Table1
Key       AttName     Rank
1          Color       1
1           type       2
1           kkk        3
2          Color       1
2           type       2
```

As seen in the above eg some keys have 2 atts while others have 3 so when i create the Pivot table and then try to label the column names it doesnt work, hpw could i change this, As is displayed above key 1 has 3 attribute Names and Key 2 has only 2 due to which the error occurs
Final data:

```
Table2
Family     Assortment Group       Key       Attribute Name      Attribute Value
a                ab                1            Color              Green
a1               ab                1            Color              Yellow
a2               ab                1            type               shirt
a6               ab                1            kkkk               f
a3               ab                2            Color              Red
a4               ab                2            Type               TShirt
a5               ab                2            Color              Yellow
```

Code

```
#For loop that loops over key values; key values defined as Zone AG

Finals=[]
Finals2=[]
Finals=pd.DataFrame(Finals)
Finals2=pd.DataFrame(Finals)
for group in Select.groupby('Key'): 
    # group is a tuple where the first value is the Key and the second is the dataframe
    Final2=group[1]
    Family1=Family.merge(Final2, on='Key1', how='inner')
    result=Family1.pivot_table(index=['Family','Assortment Group','Key'], columns='Attribute Name', values='Attribute Value', aggfunc='first').reset_index()
    result.columns=['Family','Assortment Group','Key','Att1','Att2','Att3']
    Finals=Finals.append(result)
```

Traceback

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 5 elements, new values have 6 elements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the columns with a list comprehension to generate the right amount of Att columns.

```
result.columns = ['Family','Assortment Group','Key']\
                 + [f'Att{i}' for i in range(1, result.shape[1]-2)]
```

EDIT: explanation, `result.shape[1]` gives the number of columns in result. let's say it is 5, then the first 3 are the 'Family','Assortment Group','Key'. So what you want is to create 2 more Att, and `range(1, result.shape[1]-2)` is in this case `range(1, 3)` and `[f'Att{i}' for i in range(1, result.shape[1]-2)]` will then iterate for i=1 and i=2 to create the list `['Att1', 'Att2']`. add this list to the one with the 3 first columns name to get the right number of columns

Comment: Could you explain this part : ```+ [f'Att{i}' for i in range(1, result.shape[1]-2)]```

Comment: the no of attributes changes with the key, there are some lien items where it is 3 and others where it is 2.

Comment: @KarthikApadodharanan yes and in the case of 3 attributes, `result` would have 6 columns, so the `range` will be from 1 to 4 instead of 1 to 3 like in the case of 2 attributes

Comment: Exactly which isnt taken care of by this rite, or am i missing something, the 1st att in the case of 3 atts isnt assigned a column name

Comment: @KarthikApadodharanan I don't know how to explain more sorry, if result.shape[1] = 6, then [f'Att{i}' for i in range(1, result.shape[1]-2)] will be `['Att1','Att2','Att3']`, if result.shape[1] = 8, then this list comprehension becomes `['Att1', 'Att2', 'Att3', 'Att4','Att5']`, etc

Comment: Thanks, the last comment really helped